# Annotating packages at installation to ease maintenance with apt / aptitude 

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

I manage my packages with [aptitude](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/aptitude.html).

I occasionally go through my list of packages, removing obsolete
applications (in the sense that I do not want to use them any more).

For example, while I have a limited number of development libraries on my
system that I *do* want installed permanently, a lot were just there to
allow me to compile some program from source *once*, and *a long time
ago*. To make those clean-up sessions take unneeded dependencies into
account, I use [the `markauto` command of
aptitude](https://ascending.wordpress.com/2007/04/12/aptitude-tip-markauto-and-unmarkauto/).

The problem is that I sometimes can no longer trust my memory to make the
difference between packages that are transient, and things that I need to
keep (because, e.g., I will need them to recompile something
*tomorrow*). The situation is even more acute when I share administration
duties over a server with another admin. Alternatively, I wish I would
have the discipline to clean up *all* packages that are transient after
use, but history proves it's too much to hope for.

Hence : is there a tool that, like markauto would let me **annotate** packages **at
installation time**, not with a flag but with a simple comment string saying **why** they are
being installed?

Ideally, that comment would be retrievable with aptitude
(or synaptic, or whatever kids these days use to manage
packages). Ideally, this would be something that me and another admin on the same server can collaborate on, and it would thus, for example,
benefit from the same lock-management system as the package-tree already has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aptitude supports "user tags", see if they meet your requirements.

```
   add-user-tag, remove-user-tag
       Adds a user tag to or removes a user tag from the selected group of
       packages. If a package name contains a tilde ("~") or question mark
       ("?"), it is treated as a search pattern and the tag is added to or
       removed from all the packages that match the pattern (see the
       section "Search Patterns" in the aptitude reference manual).

       User tags are arbitrary strings associated with a package. They can
       be used with the ?user-tag(<tag>) search term, which will select
       all the packages that have a user tag matching <tag>.
```

Also see the options `--add-user-tag`, `--add-user-tag-to`, `--remove-user-tag`, `--remove-user-tag-from`. One example usage:

```
aptitude install cinnamon --add-user-tag "for=cinnamon; date=$(date)"
```

Nevertheless, I fear they are only visible/usable through `aptitude`.

Comment: Yes ! This is perfect ! Notable points : the user-tag is retrievable through `aptitude show`, displayed in the aptitude info dialog, and can be an arbitrary long string (with spaces, etc)